# Как дать понять BlurEffect не размывать при 0

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Доброго времени суток

Есть `BlurEffect` в `Grid`

```
<Grid.Effect>
    <BlurEffect Radius="{Binding GridBlurRadius}" KernelType="Gaussian"/>
</Grid.Effect>
```

В `GridBlurRadius` передаю значения. Но при 0 значение размытие все равно имеется, но хотелось бы каким-либо способом убирать blur когда он не нужен.

Есть ли какие-либо способы это сделать?

Comment: Отключить триггером попробуйте

Comment: @АндрейNOP что значит отключить? У этого эффекта нет свойства IsEnable или что-либо похожего. Я нашел только то что в Radius передают null из codebehind.Я извратился и попробовал тоже передать null. Ошибок нет, как и эффекта. А добавлять к Grid BlurEffect и удалять его каждый раз - думаю это так не должно работать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отключите эффект триггером, если в свойстве лежит 0:

```
<Grid.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <BlurEffect Radius="{Binding Radius}" KernelType="Gaussian"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Radius}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Grid.Style>
```

Обратите внимание, установку эффекта при этом надо обязательно перенести в стиль, иначе триггер будет иметь более низкий приоритет.

Comment: идеально работает! Спасибо!